# Access objects within ArrayList

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have an SQLite database with a table called `author`. I'm trying to pull the `id` and `name` values and pass them to the MainActivity where `id` will be stored as a variable and `name` will be displayed in a ListView.

The `name` side of things is working fine, but I'm unsure how to get the `id` value in my MainActivity. I've tried the `get` method of ArrayList on `authorList` with no luck.

Snippet from DatabaseHelper:

```
public List<Author> getAllAuthors() {
    List<Author> authorList = new ArrayList<>();
    // Select all query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + AUTHORS + " ORDER BY name_alphabetic";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            // create new author object
            Author author = new Author();
            // set ID and name of author object
            author.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            author.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            // pass author object to authorList array
            authorList.add(author);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    // return author list
    return authorList;
}
```

Author class:

```
public class Author {
    int id;
    String name;
    String name_alphabetic;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    public Author() {
    }

    public Author(int id, String name, String name_alphabetic) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.name_alphabetic = name_alphabetic;
    }

    // getters
    public int getID() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getNameAlphabetic() {
        return this.name_alphabetic;
    }

    // setters
    public void setID(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setNameAlphabetic(String name_alphabetic) {
        this.name_alphabetic = name_alphabetic;
    }
}
```

Snippet from MainActivity:

```
// connect authorsListView variable to XML ListView
authorsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.authors_list_view);

// create new database helper
DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

// create new list through getAllAuthors method (in DatabaseHelper class)
List authorList = db.getAllAuthors();

Log.i("authors", authorList.toString());

// create new Array Adapter
ArrayAdapter<Author> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, authorList);

// link ListView and Array Adapter
    authorsListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

// onItemClickListener waits for user to tap a ListView item
        authorsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                String author = authorsListView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

                //Log.i("click", author);

                // new Intent specifies which Activity to move from and to
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StoriesActivity.class);
                // adds extra author variable to the Intent
                intent.putExtra("author", author);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

**EDIT:**

I've tried return `authorList.get(0)` and `return authorList.get(id)` (although I'm aware `id` hasn't been set). The purpose of passing this variable is so later in MainActivity I can pass it to another Activity using an Intent extra, i.e. `intent.putExtra("author", author_id)`.

Comment: It would be helpful to see some code, or even pseudocode, that shows what you _want_ to do. Your question says "I'm unsure how to get the id value in my MainActivity" but that's not really enough for me to answer. I'd like to know what you're trying to do with this id value.

Comment: @BenP. Hey, thanks for your response. I've made an edit - is that any clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, I see this:

> ```
> List authorList = db.getAllAuthors();
> ```

You should probably define this as `List<Author>` instead of just `List`, so that the `get()` method will return an `Author` instead of an `Object`. Once you've made that change, you should be able to access the author's `id` like this:

```
List<Author> authorList = db.getAllAuthors();
int id = authorList.get(0).getID(); // the id of the first author in the list
```

Note that general rules for `List` apply here, so if the list is empty then `get(0)` will throw an exception.

### Update

You can use the `AdapterView.getItemAtPosition(int)` method to access the data object that has been clicked on inside your `OnItemClickListener`. Because you defined your `ArrayAdapter` as `ArrayAdapter<Author>`, you're guaranteed that `getItemAtPosition()` will return an `Author` instance, so you could write code like this:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Author author = (Author) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StoriesActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("author_id", author.getID());
    intent.putExtra("author_name", author.getName());

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

As you start working with more complex objects, if you find that it gets annoying adding each individual field (like `name` and `id`) to the `Intent` one by one, you could look into implementing the `Parcelable` interface on your objects: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

Then you could just add the `Author` to the `Intent` directly, instead of adding its fields.

Comment: Thanks, that works nicely. How would I pass that to the `onClickItemListener`? My current method of getting the author names is to add them to the ListView then set a variable based on the text in that ListView item, but that won't work given the `id` will never be displayed. (I've extended my MainActivity code snipped to include the `onClickItemListener`.)

Comment: @Sebastian I've updated my answer to address your question.